# PHP: php timestamp,how to get timestamp that is 10 second before the current?

Tags: php

I am checking for notification update using the php time stamp difference. The activity occurred between current time & time 10 seconds before the current time i want to capture. I am using set Interval function of java-script to check on every 10 seconds. But at the script side, in php i don't know in what dimensions time stamp to increment for each seconds. How do i count the difference for 10 seconds at php side to check for notification arrived in between that time???

My java-script function is this

```
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get('<?php echo BASE_URL.'php/processing/checkForNotification.php'?>',function( data ){

    });
}, 5000)
```

Comment: umm find notifications between `time()` and `time() - 10` ?

Comment: what is the value for 1 second getting added to timestamp of php?

Comment: time() + 1 !? if I understand what you are looking for

Comment: i tried calculating difference with the method you gave it is showing me the difference of 20 that means for 1sec. it is adding 2 into timestamp is it so??

Comment: i guess you are right? it is giving me what i am in need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$now = time();
$less_ten = (intval($now) - 10);

echo 'Now:'. date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $now);
echo 'Less:'. date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $less_ten)."<br>";
```